# Adding column in pandas with several conditions based on other columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, match

Firstly, I apologise if this is already somewhere on StackOverflow, I searched for an hour after experimenting myself for an hour and couldn't find it. I'm sure there must be an elegant (and probably elementary) solution.

I have the following data frame:

```
    Admit   Gender  Dept    Freq
0   Admitted    Male    A   512
1   Rejected    Male    A   313
2   Admitted    Female  A   89
3   Rejected    Female  A   19
4   Admitted    Male    B   353
5   Rejected    Male    B   207
6   Admitted    Female  B   17
7   Rejected    Female  B   8
8   Admitted    Male    C   120
9   Rejected    Male    C   205
10  Admitted    Female  C   202
11  Rejected    Female  C   391
12  Admitted    Male    D   138
13  Rejected    Male    D   279
14  Admitted    Female  D   131
15  Rejected    Female  D   244
16  Admitted    Male    E   53
17  Rejected    Male    E   138
18  Admitted    Female  E   94
19  Rejected    Female  E   299
20  Admitted    Male    F   22
21  Rejected    Male    F   351
22  Admitted    Female  F   24
23  Rejected    Female  F   317
```

And I want to add a column 'Proportion' which gives the proportion of successful / failed applicants by gender to each department.

So that:

```
df.loc[0, 'Proportion'] = 512/(512+313) = 0.6206
df.loc[1, 'Proportion'] = 313/(512+313) = 0.3794
...
```

and so on.

I tried to start off by adding a 'total' column using variations of:

```
data.groupby(['Dept', 'Gender'])[['Freq']].sum()
```

but I can't seem to look up the values of this dataframe by the values in each row of the original dataframe.

I have also tried using lambda functions, but I get the 'function is not iterable' error.

I suppose one could loop over it row by row as it is a small dataset, but in the future when I need to do things like this that won't be an option.

Please help out a novice and aspiring Data Scientist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide column by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html) with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for Series with same size as original `DataFrame`:

```
data['new'] = data['Freq'].div(data.groupby(['Dept', 'Gender'])['Freq'].transform('sum'))
```

Or use `apply` with custom function:

```
data['new'] = data.groupby(['Dept', 'Gender'])['Freq'].apply(lambda x: x/x.sum())
```

---

```
print (data)
       Admit  Gender Dept  Freq       new
0   Admitted    Male    A   512  0.620606
1   Rejected    Male    A   313  0.379394
2   Admitted  Female    A    89  0.824074
3   Rejected  Female    A    19  0.175926
4   Admitted    Male    B   353  0.630357
5   Rejected    Male    B   207  0.369643
6   Admitted  Female    B    17  0.680000
7   Rejected  Female    B     8  0.320000
8   Admitted    Male    C   120  0.369231
9   Rejected    Male    C   205  0.630769
10  Admitted  Female    C   202  0.340641
11  Rejected  Female    C   391  0.659359
12  Admitted    Male    D   138  0.330935
13  Rejected    Male    D   279  0.669065
14  Admitted  Female    D   131  0.349333
15  Rejected  Female    D   244  0.650667
16  Admitted    Male    E    53  0.277487
17  Rejected    Male    E   138  0.722513
18  Admitted  Female    E    94  0.239186
19  Rejected  Female    E   299  0.760814
20  Admitted    Male    F    22  0.058981
21  Rejected    Male    F   351  0.941019
22  Admitted  Female    F    24  0.070381
23  Rejected  Female    F   317  0.929619
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was hoping for.